# Generate Doc with PHP

Tags: php, generator, doc

Is it possible to generate doc with php?
What libraries are the best in generating doc?

PS.

I need library that works with UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php) which illustrates different methods.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that article... it doesn't mention a single library for generating Excel files (only using COM or fake headers with a CSV), and doesn't mention PHPWord for writing Word documents.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean generating documentation like javadoc? If so then the defacto standard use to be [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/).