# generate a landscape MS Word document with php

Tags: php, file, ms-word

The following code generates a MS Word document in portrait format. But I need it to be in landscape mode as I’m inserting some tables, charts and similar multimedia stuff.

```
<?php 
$fp = fopen("tx1.doc", 'w+');
$str="here goes some of my content";
$str.="- -I insert tables, charts and all the stuff  with alignment--";
fwrite($fp, $str);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

So I wanna know how I can force php to generate the document in landscape format (landscape suits my presentation).

**EDIT:**  as suggested by @Mark Baker I found solution to all of my requirements at one spot/shot  [github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord](http://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) Thanks. Now I can do anything with Doc ;)

Comment: How are you inserting those tables, charts and all the multimedia stuff? Doing that in Word format is usually pretty tough by hand... Are you already using some library?

Comment: Why am I thinking that you're simply writing HTML markup to your file

Comment: @deceze tables am inserting by html, multimedia is not yet included.

Comment: @MarkBaker yes am generating some html tables and saving them in doc

multimedia I've not yet included, am just trying that how much space I'll get if change portrait to landscape and am struck.

Comment: Then you're not producing an MS Word file. Just because you're calling .doc doesn't mean it is one. Use a library that can produce actual MS Word files in .doc or .docx format, which should also allow you to adjust the page properties.

Comment: @deceze well I've gone through this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4912602/1158603 it helped me but its not answering my problem, can you post any links if possible

Comment: More then enough libraries mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux

Comment: @deceze thanks. I've checked in all the links of the page, they say about good programming practices and different ways of getting things done, but my problem is not in just generating a ms word doc but its generating ms word doc with landscape format which is addressed no where

Comment: Your specific question isn't directly addressed.... but if you use some of the library tools listed that generate real .doc files (not simply html pretending to be word) then those libraries will almost certainly provide options for page layout including orientation... with html, you simply don't have that option

Comment: Starter for 1.... PHPWord ( https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord ) allows you to set page orientation in the settings, and can produce output as .docx, .odt or .rtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to generate rtf document.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1805-PHP-Create-RTF-documents-from-HTML.html